# import excel sheet not working with laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Iam trying to import excel sheet to my project using maatwebsite package , i have done everything right but iam getting some error can not handle. it keep displaying message from file in vendor telling me that (Using $this when not in object context). Here is my code:

**My Controller**

```
public function excel(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new ProductsImport(),$request->file('sizes'));

    return redirect(route($this->route . '.index'))->with('message', trans('lang.added_s'));
}
```

**vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Excel.php**

```
public function import($import, $filePath, string $disk = null, string $readerType = null)
{
    $readerType = FileTypeDetector::detect($filePath, $readerType);
    //this line below is keeping making error ( Using $this when not in object context)
    $response   = $this->reader->read($import, $filePath, $readerType, $disk);

    if ($response instanceof PendingDispatch) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html), you need to go to that **ProductsImport** file that you have created and specify what you want to do with the file.
Do you want to get a collection or create models ?  implement either "**ToModel**" or "**ToCollection**" and then add the corresponding the method

I usually chose **ToCollection** then do sth like this :

```
class ProductsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
                Product::create([
                'name' => $row['name'],
               // add the other columns 
        ]);
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to implement "**WithHeadingRow**" and add the method **headingRow** to tell the package where you're heading row is:

```
 public function headingRow(): int
{
    return 1;
}
```

Another thing you can do is store the file first before importing it.  I do that to keep track of the files imported.

```
$file = $request->file('sizes') ;
$file_name = '' //decide file name here ;
$file>storeAs('public/'.$file_name.$file->clientExtension();
```

and then I would pass that to the Excel import method :

```
Excel::import(new ProductsImport(),public_path('storage/'.$file_name));
```

**NB** : do not mess with any vendor files.